What's wrong with my edit?
I applied for this edit a few weeks ago.
https://superuser.com/review/suggested-edits/1148560

It was unanimously rejected by the reviewers. I'm not sure what I did wrong here - it seems to me that this edit made the post clearer, stripped irrelevant information out and fixed grammar.
I accept the decision of the reviewers, but I'd like to see how I could improve.

Its a bit of a harsh thing to ask  but - what's the benefit of fixing up a 8 year old, apparently abandoned question?

XP is no longer a supported OS, so if OP is still needing an answer it should be forwarded to retrocomputing ?

@Criggie - It's not eligible to be migrated. It's also within scope here; question (s) should only be migrated if they are out of scope here and within scope at the new community. The question is also abandoned.

I should have added that I wouldn’t have declined the [edit], but improved it, since there are some minor formatting and extremely minor grammatical errors still. However, it is an abandoned question, and the edit definitely will not result in an answer to the question.

Is it required that an edit must help the question achieve answers? Edits can also make the question easier to understand for people who come across it in the future, and make it more searchable.

Also, if the problem is that I'm too late to the party, I understand. However, the reject reason was that my edit did not make the question less confusing. I expected that the reviewer should say that it's too late rather than choose an unrelated reason.

@stickynotememo - The edit must be complete.  If you are changing tags of a question, then one of the goals of doing so, is making the question more discoverable. I would even argue that modifying a 8 year old question, should only be done, so it can be answered. Why is how new you are relevant to the discussion? All edits are held to the same criteria. There is no "too late" reason to reject an edit. It sounds like you need more experience in the UI of the edit approval process.

As an aside, please don't use code blocks for things that are not code.  An unordered list would be more appropriate here.

This is only my opinion. I did not vote on this edit. Take any applied upvotes/downvotes to judge whether it is a common opinion or not.
I can only guess here, but this question is so low on information to begin with it should be closed and deleted rather than edited.
If it were a new question, we would advise OP to tell us more about this firmware update they attempted, more about the keyboard and mouse, whether they'd tried alternate hardware, and at the same time we would have advised them to improve the format/layout of their question.
But, given its age it is clearly abandoned. While your edits did make the format and layout of the question no longer part of the problem, there is so little actual information regarding the problem and the context it occurs within that it needs a full reworking by OP, not any of us, before we could consider it possible to answer.
The error is not on your side: your edit was fine. Just, perhaps, use your edit skills (which you have) on more deserving questions, and for ones like this, vote to Close instead.

I was not involved with reviewing the edit, so I can't say why they rejected it.
There is one thing about the edit that is wrong.  You use code markdown to list the specs:
Windows XP SP3 Black Edition
Ram 1 GB
DirectX 9
Hard Drive About1 170 GB

They aren't code and should not get code markdown.  This will break screen readers, which will try to interpret them as code.  Instead, please use a list to list things:

Windows XP SP3 Black Edition
Ram 1 GB
DirectX 9
Hard Drive About1 170 GB

Note:  if you had output that is not code and not a list (e.g. a poem), you could mark it
Windows XP SP3 Black Edition
Ram 1 GB
DirectX 9
Hard Drive About1 170 GB
This just adds two spaces at the end of each line.  However, in this case, it's a list, so list markdown is most appropriate.

Code markdown is often used for this because it is very nice on human eyes.

@mdfst13 there could be nicer way to explain that code markdown confuses screen reader for those visually disabled (or rather, confuses them?)

@music2myear using code markdown for formatting is harmful to those who depend on screen reader for accessibility. Please use other formatting for emphasis or eyecatching, like bold, italic, or quote (using >)
